# Differential save on child entities with Entity Framework 7.0.0-rc1 / EntityFrameworkCore 1.0.0

Tags: c#, angularjs, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I have an application based on ASP.Net MVC 6 / ASP.Net Core 1.0, which exposes CRUD methods through a Web API.

I am using Entity Framework 7.0.0-rc1, I plan to migrate everything to EF Core 1.0 / ASP.Net Core 1.0 but haven't done this yet.

Here's a snippet of the type of model which causes me an design issue :

```
public class ParentEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ChildEntity> ChildCollection { get; set; } = new ChildCollection();
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ParentEntity ParentEntity { get; set; }
    public int? ParentEntityId { get; set; }
}
```

All relationships are properly ensured in my `ApplicationContext` class, and all CRUD operations work as expected, including Adds and Updates of the Child entities when a ParentEntity is saved.

For example, here's the kind of Save method I expose through the API :

```
// On some web API Save method :
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Save(ParentEntity entity)
{
    if (entity.Id > 0) _context.Update(entity);
    else _context.Add(entity);
    var result = _context.SaveChanges();
    return Json(result);
}
```

The entity passed to the save method is coming from my AngularJS backend. As long as child entities have been added or modified, everything works as expected.

Let's now imagine the back end has received a `ParentEntity` loaded with two `ChildEntity` named `A` and `B`.

Now on the backend I remove the B child entity and post it to the save method.

The backend saves the changes of the data it receives : all updates are persisted on `ParentEntity` and on `ChildEntity` A.

But the B `ChildEntity` remains in the datastore, which seem logical since there was no indication on what to do with it.

**So my question is**, since it seems to me it is a very common case : how do I deal with that ?

I have imagined storing somewhere the child collection, save the changes, reload the root entity, compare the collection, determine which should be removed, then remove it, but it seems pretty hard and dirty work to me. Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is here

https://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/magazine/mt694083

Comment: Very interesting post about how state tracking mechanisms have been implemented from ADO.Net Datasets to EF Core, through EF <= 4 with ObjectContext and EF >= 4.1 and DbContext. Thus, as far as I understood, it doesn't quite explain how to solve the specific problem of dealing with differential delete of child objects within a disconnected entity.

Answer (score 0):

According to some tips explained in the MSDN blog post above, I have implemented a Client state field on every entity, through it's base class :

```
public enum ObjectState
{
    Unchanged = 0,
    Added = 1,
    Modified = 2,
    Deleted = 3
}

public interface IObjectWithState
{
    ObjectState ClientState { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseEntity : IBaseEntity, IPrimaryKey
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public bool IsNew => Id <= 0;
    [NotMapped]
    public ObjectState ClientState { get; set; } = ObjectState.Unchanged;
}
```

Whenever a child entity is removed from a collection on the client side, instead of being physically removed and never posted back, I will keep it on the collection, and mark it as deleted.

Then I just have to deal with that on server side :

```
_context.ChildEntityCollection.RemoveRange(
    entity.ChildCollection.Where(c => c.ClientState == ObjectState.Deleted).ToList()
);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

I implemented the whole enum on every entity, but currently I only use the Deleted value, and only through a relation. Up till now, no need for other values, or any value on root entities.